# particles in particle system rendering on the same place

Tags: particles, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

I have a particle system where I want to use a vertex group for the density(normal stuff).

But I am also using a vertex weight edit modifier with a mask to control the vertex group.
[image]

When I'm previewing the vertex group everything seems ok.

[image]

But when I later tried to use that group in the particle system. Every particle just spawns in the same place and I have no clue why this is happening.

[image]

I have checked for solutions but the vertex weight edit doesn't have a lot of documentation

Comment: Are you using hair particles?

Comment: yes. and they are set to render as an object

Comment: Yeah, I don't know. I'm pretty sure it has to do with the Vertex Weight Modifier, but I rarely use it, and am not that familiar with it's interactions. What happens if you remove it? (not permanently - just to debug)

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong.
I needed to check use modifier stack under particle properties>>>emissione>>>sorce>>>use modifier stack